# Указать виды предложений

Tags: синтаксис, сложное-предложение

Скажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли указаны виды предложений?

*Мафисенко умел сдерживаться, а Качеременков — загораться, и они отлично понимали друг друга.* — сложносочиненное предложение.

*Учитель стыдил нас не за то, что мы курили, а за то, что солгали.* — сложное предложение с разными видами связи.

*Надо было понять, где у этого переплета верх, а где — низ.* — сложное предложение с разными видами связи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Учитель стыдил нас не за то, что мы курили, а за то, что солгали.* - Сложноподчинённое предложение с параллельным подчинением двух придаточных. Союз *а* соединяет не предложения, а однородные члены (*не за то, а за то*).

Первое предложение Вы охарактеризовали правильно. Последнее предложение - Вера права - это сложноподчинённое предложение с однородными придаточными, соединёнными сочинительной связью. Формально это предложение с РВС, но считается сложноподчинённым.

Answer (score 1):

1) Сложное предложение с сочинительной связью трех простых предложений.

2)Сложноподчиненное предложение с параллельным (неоднородным) подчинением двух придаточных.

3)  Сложноподчиненное предложение с однородным  подчинением придаточных.   Однородные придаточные всегда связаны между собой. Это или бессоюзная связь,  или они могут иметь при себе сочинительные союзы, как в данном случае.

Answer (score 0):

**Обратим внимание на предложение (2), к нему есть вопросы!**

(1) Мафисенко умел сдерживаться, а Качеременков — загораться, и они отлично понимали друг друга.

(2) **Учитель стыдил нас не за то, что мы курили, а за то, что солгали.**

(3) Надо было понять, где у этого переплета верх, а где — низ.

Предложение (1) сложносочиненное, тут нет вопросов, связь только сочинительная.

Предложение (3) сложноподчиненное с придаточными изъяснительными (дополнительного типа). Это однородное параллельное  подчинение придаточных, между собой они связаны сочинительной союзной связью. Следовательно, здесь два вида связи: подчинение и сочинение.

**А вот предложение (2) вызывает интерес.**

Его определили как неоднородное параллельное подчинение, но такое определение мне не кажется единственно правильным. Придаточные изъяснительные относятся к одному слову (стыдил) в главном предложении и **фактически связаны между собой сочинительной союзной связью,** но эта связь обозначена **через местоименные указательные слова** в главном предложении.

**Вот в этом весь интерес и сложность решения.**  И как тут быть, какое решение будет правильным?

Comment: _А вот предложение (3) вызывает интерес._ Наверно, предложение (2)?

Comment: Ну да,  предложение (2). (Я же вроде видела,  исправляла, но нет, оказывается).  А что вы думаете, какое решение правильное?